# How can I read xml on android with unity?

Tags: android, xml, unity-game-engine

So here's my code, it works perfectly fine in unity editor but not on android, it only reads the first line of the xml file.
I don't know what is wrong with it.
The file exists on the phone but it only reads the first line.
In the unity editor it works perfectly fine.
Thank for your help.

```
 using System.Xml;
 using System.Xml.Serialization;

 public class Mission
 { [XmlAttribute("id")]
 public int Id;

 public string description;
 public int ordre;

 }
```

Here is the class that loads the xml

```
using System.IO;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.Collections.Generic;

[XmlRoot("Missionss")]
 public class Missions{
 [XmlArray("Missions"), XmlArrayItem("Mission")]
 public List<Mission> Mission_List;

 private Missions(){}

 public static Missions LoadFromFile(string filepath){
     XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Missions));
     using(FileStream stream = new FileStream(filepath, FileMode.Open))
     {
         return serializer.Deserialize(stream) as Missions;
     }
 } 
 public void Save (string path)
 {
     XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer (typeof(Missions));
     using (FileStream stream = new FileStream (path, FileMode.Create)) {
         serializer.Serialize (stream, this);
     }
    }
  }
```

and finally:

```
public void LoadXML(){

     string filename="/phases.xml";
     string filename1="/missions.xml";

     phases = Phases.LoadFromFile(Application.persistentDataPath + filename);
     missions = Missions.LoadFromFile (Application.persistentDataPath + filename1);


 }

 public void save(){

     phases.Save(Application.streamingAssetsPath + "phases.xml");
     missions.Save(Application.streamingAssetsPath + "missions.xml");


 }
```

Comment: Is it intended, that you save on streamingAssetsPath, but load from persistent?

Comment: yes, I download it using the WWW class from the streamingAssets and i write it in the persistent and then I load it again from the persistent. It's the only way that I found to make it work, but it only reads the first line of my second xml ( I have two xml files ).

Comment: i know, it's a bit lame, but if your xml isn't huge, you could safely store it in PlayerPrefs, and it's safe for different platforms.

Comment: I think, this might be a character encoding issue, I assume you checked: http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php?title=Save_and_Load_from_XML I recall implementing similar functionality with no problem, using that guide :S

Answer (score 0):

dont you need "\" written somewhere? lets say:  phases.Save(Application.streamingAssetsPath **+"\\"+** "phases.xml");